# Redis: (error) ERR unknown command 'redis-benchmark'

Tags: redis

I'm trying to run some redis benchmark tests, but they're all giving the same error, unknown command redis-benchmark:

```
C:\>redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> redis-benchmark -t set,get -r 1000000 -q
(error) ERR unknown command 'redis-benchmark'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run the `redis-benchmark` command inside a redis-cli shell. It's not part of the redis-cli commands. Try a regular prompt instead:

Not working:

```
C:\>redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> redis-benchmark -t set,get -r 1000000 -q
```

Working:

```
C:\>redis-benchmark -t set,get -r 1000000 -q
```

Outputs something like:

```
SET: 111856.82 requests per second
GET: 108225.10 requests per second
```